# What are disadvantages of using ThreadPoolExecutor as queue?

Tags: java, executorservice, java.util.concurrent

For conventional Producer-Consumer problem, we can use ExecutorService as queue. What are disadvantages of it? Is it less efficient? Because creation of thread is costly.

```
executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(90);
// This will be called many times concurrently
public void processObjectsWithFixedSetOfThreads(Foo objectToProcess) {
   //Create a new thread and submit (executor is of fixed size hence extra tasks will be queued)
   executor.submit(new ObjectProcessorWorker(objectToProcess));
}

class ObjectProcessorWorker implements Runnable() {
  public ObjectProcessorWorker(Foo obj) {
     this.obj = obj;
  }

  public void run() {
     longRunningProcess(obj);
  }

}
```

Why [BlockingQueue](https://github.com/TheNilesh/asyncmodel/blob/master/asyncmodel/src/main/java/com/nilesh/asyncmodel/blockingqueue/Worker.java) is recommended for Producer-Consumer problem however it can be done [without that](https://github.com/TheNilesh/asyncmodel/tree/master/asyncmodel/src/main/java/com/nilesh/asyncmodel/executorservice) too (As shown above)?

### EDIT

Many people are not getting the difference because ThreadPoolExecutor internally maintains the BlockingQueue.

In a biscuit factory there is a task of wrapping biscuits. If I am its owner I have two ways to speed up wrapping task.

1. Put biscuits and wrapper on assembly line have 10 workers doing work of wrapping.

   I -> `queue.put(biscuits, wrapper)`

   Worker -> `queue.take()`
2. Creating a task of wrapping biscuits putting it on a assembly line, and let the 10 workers do that.

   I -> `new Task(biscuits, wrapper)`

   Worker -> `task = queue.take(); do(task);`

I am asking the disadvantages of the later one.

Comment: They're not really the same thing at all. The executor service is running things from a queue (it has a blocking queue internally, holding the submitted tasks); it's not the queue itself.

Comment: @AndyTurner I have added an edit.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you define ThreadPoolExecutore.. as shown bellow

```
ExecutorService threadPoolExecutor =
        new ThreadPoolExecutor(
                corePoolSize,
                maxPoolSize,
                keepAliveTime,
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>()
                );
```

If less than **corePoolSize** threads are created in the the thread pool when a task is delegated to the thread pool, then a new thread is created, even if idle threads exist in the pool.

If the internal queue of tasks is full, and corePoolSize threads or more are running, but less than **maximumPoolSize** threads are running, then a new thread is created to execute the task

Now if you have defined **blocking queue**... than after **corePoolSize** , it will add new threads in to queue... till the capacity of queue reached.
And after overflowing **queue**, it will generate new threads upto **maximumPoolSize**.

Don't know what is dis advantage of using ExecutorService as queue. I dont think there is any disadvantages.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a `ThreadPoolExecutor` using [`Executors.newFixedThreadPool(int)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/Executors.java#88), you are creating a `BlockingQueue`:

```
public static ExecutorService newFixedThreadPool(int nThreads) {
    return new ThreadPoolExecutor(nThreads, nThreads,
                                  0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                                  new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
}
```

As such, you're not doing it "without" a blocking queue if you a thread pool created in this way; it's just hidden from you.

Comment: I agree that BlockingQueue is created internally. But when executing `new Runnable()` there might be overhead due to creation of thread. However if I create `BlockingQueue<Foo>` then thread creation never happens.

Comment: Of course no thread is created: a queue doesn't create threads, it's just a queue.

Comment: "without Blocking Queue" means using internal BQ.